# How do I add a script to a Google Sheet to automatically take data from an XLSX file on Google Drive?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to automatically update a Google Sheet from a separate XLSX file, since the XLSX file gets regularly updated, but I need to do some data cleaning. I tried doing a `query` and `importrange` neither of which can get data from an xlsx file.

It seems like I need to write a script on the Google Sheet to automatically take the data from the xlsx. Where do I add this, and how would I go about getting started? I have access to both files, so permissions shouldn't  be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion: Temporarily Convert the Excel File to Google Sheets File to Extract Data

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to extract data from Excel files to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script. As a workaround, you need to first convert your excel file to Google Sheets and then extract the data from the converted file to your output Google Sheets file. You may use the following script as a basis for yours:

```
function importData() {
  var xlsxName = "Test 1.xlsx"; //Change source file name accordingly
  var convertID = convert(xlsxName).toString();
  var xLSX = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertID).getSheetByName("Input");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<output Sheet ID>").getSheetByName("Output"); //Change output sheet ID
  var lastColumn = xLSX.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = xLSX.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).setValues(xLSX.getDataRange().getValues()); //Sets values from converted xlsx data to output sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(convertID).setTrashed(true); //deletes temporary file
}

function convert(excelFileName) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(excelFileName);
  var excelFile = (files.hasNext()) ? files.next() : null;
  var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
  var config = {
    title: "[Converted File] " + excelFile.getName(), //sets the title of the converted file
    parents: [{ id: excelFile.getParents().next().getId() }],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(config, blob);
  return (spreadsheet.id); //Returns the ID of the converted file
}
```

This script involves:

1. Converting the Excel file to a temporary Google Sheets file.
2. Importing the data from the temporary Google Sheets file to the desired/output Google Sheets file.
3. Deleting the temporary Google Sheets file.

**NOTE:**

1. Expect a longer runtime when applying this script to a bigger excel file.
2. You may modify the script to be suitable for your current issue.
3. The script should be added to your desired output Google Sheets.
4. Do not forget to add the `Drive API` service to your script.

### Sample Test Case:

Input:

[image: Input]

Expected Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: Bummer, I thought there would be a way to do this without having to do that manual step of converting to Google Sheets. I want to automate the process after the xlsx file gets updated, so manually converting the file defeats this purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft Excel files are not fully supported by Google since it is not a Google product. If you try and open an Excel file uploaded in your Google Drive, the option to add a script using Google Apps Script (Extensions > Apps Script) is not visible. Thus, there is a need to convert the Excel file into Google Sheets format before applying Google Apps Scripts.

Comment: Another workaround that I can think of is to apply a time based trigger to the script that I have provided to your output Google Sheets. Again, all I can give are suggestions since Google does not fully support Microsoft Excel (especially Google Apps Script).